# Show Previous and Next icon over popup image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show next and previous on over the pop up images. Unfortunately, the icon still stay behind the popup image. I have set the z-index to it but it still stay behind the pop up.
html:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <ul class="image-list">
            <li><img src="photos/g1.jpg" alt="Photo number 1" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" onclick="view(this.src)"/></li>
            <li><img src="photos/g2.jpg" alt="Photo number 2" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" onclick="view(this.src)"/></li>
        </ul>
         <div class="navigation" id="nav">
            <span class="previous glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left" id="prev" onclick="prev()"></span>
            <span class="next glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right" id="next" onclick="next()"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.pup
    {
        width: 100%; height: 100%;
        background: #666;
        opacity: 0.7;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px; left: 0px;
        z-index: 111;
        display: none;
    }
    .viewer{
        background: #666; padding: 12px;
        position: fixed; z-index: 222;
        text-align: center;
        display: none;
    }
    #nav{
        display: none;
        background:red;
        z-index: 333;
        color: #FFF;
    }
```

javscript

```
function view(src)
        {
            var viewer = document.getElementById("viewer");
            viewer.innerHTML ='<img src="' + src + '" id="img"/>';
            var img = document.getElementById("img");
            var iw=0, ih=0;
            var dw=0, dh=0;
            img.onload=function(){
                document.getElementById("ov").style.display="block"; 
                viewer.style.display="block";
                document.getElementById("nav").style.display="block";
                iw = viewer.offsetWidth;
                ih = viewer.offsetHeight;
                dw = window.innerWidth;
                dh = window.innerHeight;
                viewer.style.top = parseInt(dh/2-ih/2) + "px";
                viewer.style.left = parseInt(dw/2-iw/2) + "px";
            };
        }
        function hide2()
        {
            document.getElementById("viewer").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("ov").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("nav").style.display="none";
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this scenario, do not attempt to give `position: fixed`, instead try giving `position: absolute`. This can be easily done using CSS. Have a look at this snippet:

```css
.slider, .slider .slides, .slider li {list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: relative; width: 400px; height: 200px;}
.slider li {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;}
.slider li:first-child {z-index: 1;}

.slider .slider-controls a {position: absolute; text-decoration: none; font-size: 1.5em; color: #000; z-index: 10; top: 50%; left: 0; background-color: #000; color: #fff; width: 35px; line-height: 32px; text-align: center; height: 35px; border-radius: 100%; top: 100px; margin-top: -16px; right: 10px; left: auto;}
.slider .slider-controls a:first-child {left: 10px; right: auto;}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/6" alt="Slide" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/2" alt="Slide" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/3" alt="Slide" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/4" alt="Slide" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/5" alt="Slide" /></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="slider-controls">
    <a href="#">&laquo;</a>
    <a href="#">&raquo;</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Full code with JavaScript:**

```js
$(function () {
  $(".slides li").hide();
  $(".slides li:first-child").show();
  $(".slider-controls a:nth-child(1)").click(function () {
    curSlide = $(".slides li:visible");
    $(".slides li").hide();
    if (curSlide.prev().length)
      curSlide.prev().show();
    else
      curSlide.parent().find("li:last-child").show();
    return false;
  });
  $(".slider-controls a:nth-child(2)").click(function () {
    curSlide = $(".slides li:visible");
    $(".slides li").hide();
    if (curSlide.next().length)
      curSlide.next().show();
    else
      curSlide.parent().find("li:first-child").show();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.slider, .slider .slides, .slider li {list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: relative; width: 400px; height: 200px;}
.slider li {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;}
.slider li:first-child {z-index: 1;}

.slider .slider-controls a {position: absolute; text-decoration: none; font-size: 1.5em; color: #000; z-index: 10; top: 50%; left: 0; background-color: #000; color: #fff; width: 35px; line-height: 32px; text-align: center; height: 35px; border-radius: 100%; top: 100px; margin-top: -16px; right: 10px; left: auto;}
.slider .slider-controls a:first-child {left: 10px; right: auto;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li id="slide-1"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/6" alt="Slide" /></li>
    <li id="slide-2"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/2" alt="Slide" /></li>
    <li id="slide-3"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/3" alt="Slide" /></li>
    <li id="slide-4"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/4" alt="Slide" /></li>
    <li id="slide-5"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/5" alt="Slide" /></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="slider-controls">
    <a href="#">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a href="#">&rsaquo;</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if I want, when click on the icon and the image change, how can i do that?

Comment: For that you need JavaScript.

Comment: @ChheangPhearum Thanks for your patience. See the updated answer. Ask if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you. When I have problem I will ask you again.

Comment: Which is a plugin? @ChheangPhearum?

Comment: After I mix you code with my code, my image was hidden. Could you check your code with my JavaScript code above?

Comment: I mean that your code is a simple code? It is not a plugin code?

Comment: No no... It is just a simple code that works. You can tweak it however you want. `:D`

Comment: I can not make it work with plnkr. Maybe I need time to it.

Comment: Now it is ok. Could you access to this link: http://plnkr.co/edit/JBTE1RAEZburUTRkVrLE?p=preview

Comment: @ChheangPhearum It doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: For me it is ok. Maybe problem with the internet. I'm not sure about that. Could you copy those code and run on your local? I think it is ok.

Comment: Yea, that's possible. @ChheangPhearum. Get my email address from my profile page. `:)`

Comment: Excuse me, I don't see your email address.

Comment: That's big and bold in my profile. Where did you see?

Comment: I click on your name.

Comment: Could you print screen it?  this is my email: pherum.chheang@gmail.com.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting a `position:relative` on the #nav, z-index needs a position set.

```
#nav {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: You have a huge amount of points. Can't you answer in a better way?

Comment: @PraveenKumar thank you for the feedback. im not sure what could be improved. I provide a solution, and a reason for why the solution works