# Reduce execution time on simple select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

```
SELECT sub_id, quo_id
FROM cos_emails WITH (nolock)
WHERE quo_id = 999624 AND sub_id = 771336
```

This query executes in 50 seconds and returns only one record. There are 16747425 records in the table.

How to reduce execution time?

Comment: Do you have an index on those columns?

Comment: Please read [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/). The preferred way to reduce select statements execution times is by creating proper indexes.

Comment: I assume these two are not part of primary key. Create `non clustered` or `non clustered column store` index on these two columns and run it again.

Comment: `CREATE /*UNIQUE*/ NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix ON dbo.cos_emails (quo_id, sub_id)`

Comment: SELECT 771336 AS sub_id, 999624 AS quo_id

Answer (score 1):

First of all

1. Show us the execution plan
2. Pretty sure, that there are missing indexes
3. If a table scan or a clustered index scan is occurring, it means it will consume a lot of resources and hence take time to return result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32005302/show-previous-and-next-icon-over-popup-image